# Scrollbar flicker

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, scrollbar

I have a problem with the way my scrollbars are drawn. Because of external limitations (my application being a plugin running in an external window that insists on painting over any regular child window), I have to use `SCROLLBAR`-class windows (as opposed to using `WS_CHILD | WS_VSCROLL`)

For almost every message received, the scrollbar is shown animating smoothly and consistently. However, when I receive the `SB_LINEDOWN` message(i.e. when I click on the bottom/right arrow), the scroll bar flickers horribly ([Low-framerate example](http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=b5455w&s=3)). Again, all other messages work perfectly.

I have tested removing the scrollbar position update (Still broken) and removing the actual scrolling code (Still broken). I am already double-buffering the area to prevent an even worse flickering..

What might cause this and how could I fix it?

Comment: That's really weird, and I honestly have no idea.  It might help me, and will almost certainly help someone else, if you post some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what Goz mentioned, which I bet you're already doing, it may be worth experimenting with combinations of WS_CLIPCHILDREN and WS_CLIPSIBLINGS on the scrollbar window itself and its container or any overlapping windows.

Comment: I still need to test a bit further, but it seems adding the WS_CLIPCHILDREN to the parent works.

Answer (score 0):

Try intercepting and ignoring the WM_ERASEBKGND this has helped me a lot with flicker in controls.  Dunno if its your problem though :(